# Unexpected token import at routes.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am trying to learn `react + express`. Here is the folder structure I am following .

```
app
 -client
   -components
     -home.jsx
 -nodemodules
 -server
 -config.js        
 -package.json
 -routes.js
```

**Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "job-application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "making a website using MERN ",
  "main": "nodemon config.js",
  "scripts": {
      "start": "node config.js"
  },
  "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git+https://github.com/devarashetty/webApplication.git"
  },
  "author": "sairam",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
      "url": "https://github.com/devarashetty/webApplication/issues"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "babel-core": "^6.0.14",
      "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
      "webpack": "^1.12.2",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
      "express": "3.x",
      "http": "*",
      "react": "*",
      "react-dom": "*",
      "react-router": "*",
      "react-router-dom": "*",
      "react-router-config": "*",
      "nodemon": "*",
      "mongodb": "*",
      "semantic-ui-react": "*"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/devarashetty/webApplication#readme"
}
```

**Routes.js**

```
import HomePage from './client/components/home';
```

I am getting error `Unexpected token import`.What's the reason behind this.I thought import was a default function availble in javascript

**config.js**

```
var http = require("http");
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var routes = require("./routes.js");
var Router = require('react-router');

server.listen(8000);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("------------", req.url);
  var router = Router.create({
      location: req.url,
      routes: routes
  });
  router.run(function(Handler, state) {
      var html = React.renderToString( < Handler / > )
      return res.render('react_page', {
          html: html
     })
  })
});

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/catering';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   if (err) {
       console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:',     err);
   } else {
       console.log('Connection established to', url);

       db.close();
   }
});
```

Comment: @BelminBedak I created a package.json file , added the required dependencies and did `npm install`.I though `babel` will take care of converting the `es6` code to `javascript` hence I added it too .But still it happens.

Comment: Please post code of config.js

Comment: @HariLamichhane I will post it

Comment: @HariLamichhane Please  check as I  have added code for that config.js

Comment: I am posting a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution that is working and may not be the best solution :)

First in your `package.json` change `start` key as below.

```
"start": "node ./bin/www"
```

Now create a folder called `bin` with a file called `www` inside it [Note: it doesn't have any extension]

Put following code inside `www`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require("babel-register")({
  presets: ["es2015", "react"],
});
var app = require('../app');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

Fourth, rename `config.js` to `app.js` and add `module.exports = app` at the end of the file

Make sure you have these dependencies in your `package.json`
[The version can be newer]

```
"babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
"babel-core": "^6.18.2",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
```

Now you can use `import` in other files except the files used above.